# Trying to inherit from a class and add a attribute on it, getting a TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Api::ApiResponse
  attr_accessor :success, :errors
  def initialize(success, errors)
    @success = success
    @errors = errors
  end
end


class NewSessionResponse < Api::ApiResponse
  attr_accessor :user
end
```

In my controller action I have this:

```
ar = NewSessionResponse.new(true, [])

ar.user = user
render json: ar
```

For some reason I am getting this error:

```
TypeError (superclass mismatch for class NewSessionResponse)
```

When I run this code in rails console it works fine.

BTW, the constructor of the parent class gets passed down to subclasses?

Comment: I suspect instead of ```response json: ar``` you mean ```render json: ar``` ? Also, does NewSessionResponse class have a method ```to_json```, to be used in that construction?

Comment: I think your issue is that you need to define an `as_json` method, which returns some sort of object that can be normally serialized by Rails (array, hash, number, string, etc). When you call to_json on an object, it uses as_json, and right now Rails has no idea how to serialize this. Here’s an example of what you could return in your as_json method `{:success => @success, :errors => @errors}`

Comment: @Nate in my rails console it responded to .to_json just fine, that's why I am confused.